# Play 4 notes instead of 1

Tags: javascript

http://serene-mountain-4924.herokuapp.com/ Simon Says (takes a few seconds to load b/c it's on a free hosting site)

How do I make it play 4 notes at the beginning instead of starting with one?

```
    this.playPattern = function() { // playback a pattern
        var next = Math.random() * INPUTS.length >> 0,
            i = 0,
            local_spacing;
        PATTERN[PATTERN.length] = next;
        SPACING = SPACING - 30;
        SPACING = Math.max(SPACING, 60);
        (function play() { // recursive loop to play pattern
            setTimeout( function() {
                SELF.playSingle( INPUTS[ PATTERN[i] ]);
                i++;
                if( i < PATTERN.length ) {
                    play();
                } else {
                    setTimeout( function() { LISTEN = true; }, SPEED );
                }
            },
            SPEED + SPACING)
        })(); // end recursion
    }
```

Comment: Bug(?): I can't even click start. It says I can click but instead I *have* to touch to start.

Comment: Oh, interesting... click's working for Google Chrome and touch is working for Safari on iOS. I'll check out different browsers and see. Thanks for bringing this to our attention! Update: Also working on Safari for desktop.

Comment: It does work if the device can only click or touch, but when it can do both such as many laptops do these days, clicking doesn't work anymore.